# Make custom link in customer account navigation visible to certain customers only

Tags: magento2, customer-account

How can I make a custom link in customer account navigation visible to certain customers only?

Example: I have a link labeled "Ticket management". If a user clicks on that he is redirected to a page where he can view and edit tickets. I want only display this link to customers that have a certain custom variable set.

Can I specify this in customer_account.xml or somewhere else?

This is my customer_account.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-tickets-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">ticket_module/index/display</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Tickets</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the class

```
/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Account/Navigation.php
```

ans the function `getLinks()` where all the customer account links are collected. Then using a reference or a plugin you can extend the functionality of the `getLinks()` function, and check if the customer has a certain custom variable set, and if not then skip this link.